# Finding the covariance of coordinates of a circle.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, covariance

Let $C$ be a circle around the origin with radius $R$. Let $R = r$ be fixed. Take  $U$ uniformly distributed on the circumference of $C$ and write $U$ = $(X, Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are the Cartesian coordinates of $U$. Find $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What is the distribution of $U$? How does this help you?

Comment: @jeremy909 I didnt even know where to start to be honest. The distribution of is uniform so we know a random angle between 0 and $2\pi$ is chosen. im not sure how this helps though

Comment: $rcos\theta$ and $rsin\theta$ will define your x and y coordinates. The pdf has to integrate to 1, for both.

Comment: By antisymmetry the covariance must be null. $\int X\,d\theta=\int Y\,d\theta=\int XY\,d\theta=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get a little bit more insight with a picture:

[image]

Shown is a circle with $r=2$ around the origin. By definition of $\sin\Theta$ and $\cos\Theta$ you can see that $(X_u,Y_u) = (r\cos\Theta,r\sin\Theta)$. So clearly $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, because $X=r\cos(\arcsin\left(\frac{Y}r\right))$.

You probably know $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathsf{E}[XY]-\mathsf{E}[X]\mathsf{E}[Y].$ Well, we can find all of these expectations because we now have formulas for each of them from $\Theta$, and we know $\Theta \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,2\pi).$ I'll show you $\mathsf{E}[X]:$

$$\mathsf{E}[X] = \mathsf{E}[r\cos\Theta] = \int_0^{2\pi}r\cos(\theta)f_{\Theta}(\theta)d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}r\cos(\theta)\cfrac{1}{2\pi}d\theta = 0$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't help you find E(XY) since you don't have the pdf.

Comment: @jeremy909 If you dont mind me asking how do you then compute E[XY]?

Comment: @Jedberry Sure, $XY = (r\cos\Theta)(r\sin\Theta)$ so $E[XY] = \int_0^{2\pi}r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta f_{\Theta}(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$

Answer (score 1):

If you pick a value for X, you have just 2 options for Y that would make that point to land on the circle. In this case X and Y are not independent.

Comment: Thanks, but is it also possible to compute $Cov(X_u,Y_u)$?